# sudo error "sudo: /var/lib/sudo/approachit writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700"

Tags: 14.04, sudo

This error occurs whenever I try to work with sudo. i found this error. Now i want to resolved this error in terminal.

```
sudo: /var/lib/sudo/approachit writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700
```

Comment: " I changed the permissions of ..." what? Don't leave us hanging there!

Comment: Sorry sir there i my mistake in written . please give me solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to solve running the command:

```
sudo chown -R root:approachit /var/lib/sudo/approachit
```

Then run the command:

```
sudo chmod -R 700 /var/lib/sudo/approachit
```